# Неправильно читается из консоли строка

Tags: c#

```
  class Program
    {
        private string first, second;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program prog = new Program();
            prog.input_data();
            Console.WriteLine("Получившийся результат выполнения импликации:\n"+ prog.implication());

            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        public string input_String()
        {
            Console.Write("Введите строку: ");
            return Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public bool implication (bool reason, bool result)
        {
            return !(reason && !result);
        } 

        public void input_data()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Первый аргумент.");
            first = input_String();
            Console.Write("Второй аргумент.");
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Должен быть той же длины, что и первый.");
                second = input_String();
            } while (first.Length == second.Length);
        }

        bool check_contains(char argument)
        {
            switch (argument)
            {
                case '1': return true;
                case '0': return false;
                default :
                    Console.WriteLine("Обнаружен посторонний знак, должны быть только '1' или '0'");
                    return false;
            }
        }

        char translate (bool argument)
        {
            return (argument) ? '1' : '0';
        }

        string implication()
        {
            string result="";
            for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
                result += translate(implication(check_contains(first[i]), check_contains(second[i])));

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Почему-то для считывания символов второй строки требуется ввести на один символ больше. При этом в методе `input_data()` срабатывает выход из цикла `do...while`, хотя вроде бы не должен.

Comment: Это консольное приложение.

Comment: У вас условие : пока длинна строк совпадает - повторять цикл. чтобы выйти из него нужна другая длинна строки  - отличающаяся от первой. возможно вам нужно исправить уловие while ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void input_data()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Первый аргумент.");
            first = input_String();
            Console.Write("Второй аргумент.");
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Должен быть той же длины, что и первый.");
                second = input_String();
            } while (first.Length != second.Length);
        }
```

Надо было всего лишь изменить условие в `while`.